# API для отправки SMS

Tags: sms

Помогите с поиском API для ***бесплатной*** немассовой отправки SMS. Требования:

1. Возможность отправки по всему миру (хотя вполне хватит связки Россия-Беларусь-Украина)
2. Бесплатность. А то куда ни глянь, везде просят заплатить.
3. Отсутствие регистрации.

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого.
Только если с сайтов операторов.

А сейчас все ОПСОСы внезапно(!) совершенно несговариваясь подняли цены на смс (для смс-шлюзов) в несколько раз -- поэтому и не будет.

Comment: >Нет такого.

Есть. Я пробовал взаимодействовать с сайтом afreesms.com (api у них нет, поэтому пришлось всё делать ручками), успешно получал их капчу, но ничего не получалось, так как при отправке всегда выводилась какая-то неведомая ошибка.

Comment: Попробовал отправить, не пришла.

До нового года 2 ОПСОСа и ещё 2 после НГ (из "большой четверки") запретили непрямые подключения к их шлюзам.

Как следствие цена на смс с 9 копеек увеличилась до 56 за 1 смс. Потому что отсылать можно через прямое подключение к шлюзу оператора.

Халява кончилась.

Comment: Я где-то слышал, то что есть лимит подключений к шлюзам с одного IP. Как раз соль в том, что сообщения будут уходить с самых разных IP - я хочу написать клиент для халявной отправки SMS с андроида. А для этого мне нужен или API, или что-то ещё бесплатное.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, не взлетит... хотя попробуйте...  
У меня было такое приложение на симбиан, оно пойдет чтобы подшутить, но постоянно с него переписываться не получится, потому что приходит смс с одного номера, а отвечать нужно на другой. Это в случае смс в чистом виде как оно есть, а это жутко бесит.  
Если же у другого человека будет такая же программа и она будет специальным образом слеплять разные смс в одну ветвь диалога, то это тоже не очень - зачем использовать смс как транспорт, когда есть целый интернет, ведь работа через гейт подразумевает наличие интернета.

Comment: То есть сейчас будет легче написать программу-чат, а не клиент для работы с смс?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, скорее всего да.  
Просто даже если посмотреть на всякие Viber, Line итп - они же сразу показывают, что у человека из Ваших контактов тоже установлен Viber (Line) и можно не писать ему смс, а отправить через мессенджер, если хочется сэкономить.  
Да и экономия на спичках может боком выйти- например даже если будет открыто подключение, передан 1кб, закрыто подключение, то оператор округлит это до 100кб (50кб у некоторых операторов), а при нынешних расценках не безлимитного траффика это от 80 до 100 копеек, так что не сильная экономия получится.